# bower + gulp: main-bower-files fails to grab backbone-amd and underscore-amd?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, ember.js, underscore.js, gulp

`main-bower-files` fails to grab `backbone-amd` and `underscore-amd`, any ideas why and how can I fix it?

gulpfile.js

```
var mainBowerFiles = require('main-bower-files');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var filter = require('gulp-filter');

gulp.task('js', function() {
    var jsFiles = ['app/scripts/*'];
    gulp.src(mainBowerFiles().concat(jsFiles))
        .pipe(filter('*.js'))
        .pipe(concat('main.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dest + 'js'));
 });
```

bower.json,

```
{
  "name": "requirejs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "requirejs": "latest",
    "jquery": "latest",
    "backbone-amd": "latest",
    "underscore-amd": "latest",
    "ember": "latest",
    "ember-data": "latest"
  },
  "authors": [
    "xxx"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "app/scripts/vendor",
    "test",
    "tests"
  ]
}
```

main.js,

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    'jquery': 'vendor/jquery/dist/jquery',
    'underscore': 'vendor/underscore-amd/underscore',
    'backbone': 'vendor/backbone-amd/backbone',
  }
});

require(['views/app'], function(AppView) {
  new AppView;
  console.log($(".div").length);
});
```

It only manage to compress `jquery`, `ember`, and `ember-data` `into one main.js file`, **accept** `backbone-amd` and `underscore-amd`

I tested with other methods,

```
gulp.task('bower', function() {
  return gulp.src(mainBowerFiles(), {
      base: 'app/scripts/vendor/'
    })
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/lib'));
});
```

or,

```
// grab libraries files from bower_components, minify and push in /public
gulp.task('libs', function() {

    var jsFilter = filter('*.js');

    return gulp.src(mainBowerFiles())

    // grab vendor js files from bower_components, minify and push in /public
    .pipe(jsFilter)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dest + '/js/vendor'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(rename({
        suffix: ".min"
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dest + '/js/vendor'))
    .pipe(jsFilter.restore());
});
```

same result - it is ignoring `backbone-amd` and `underscore-amd`. Is it a **bug** in `main-bower-files`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a bug. [`backbone-amd`](https://github.com/amdjs/backbone) and [`underscore-amd`](https://github.com/amdjs/underscore) don't have bower.json and thus no main property that could specify main files. Here is Ember's [bower.json](https://github.com/components/ember/blob/master/bower.json) for comparison.

"This will read your bower.json, iterate through your dependencies and returns an array of files defined in the main property of the packages bower.json."

https://github.com/ck86/main-bower-files#usage

You can add `overrides` property to **your** bower.json to specify right files yourself:

```
"overrides": {
    "backbone-amd": {
      "main": "backbone.js"
    },
    "underscore-amd": {
      "main": "underscore.js"
    }
}
```

https://github.com/ck86/main-bower-files#overrides-options

Comment: thanks. so it is an issue with  backbone-amd and underscore-amd then?

Comment: can we just add  bower.json in them?

Comment: @tealou I added alternative fix to answer.